# Does hotmail use ARF for its feedback loop message?

Tags: email, feedback-loop

I am working on a program to parse ARF (Abure Reporting Format) messages. It turns out I need to be able to handle Hotmail feedback loop messages as well.

Does hotmail use ARF for its feedback loop message? If not, which format is it using?

I found [this site](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Email-ARF-Hotmail/Email/ARF/Hotmail.pm.html) providing a perl parser to convert hotmail messages to ARF format which make me think it is not using it.

I read somewhere it was using JMR (Junk Mail Reporting) but I can't found any example of such a message on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unlike e.g. AOL Hotmail doesn't use the ARF. Instead you'll get emails with the subject "complaint about message from [ip]* from "staff@hotmail.com", which contain the original body.

Comment: Do you have a source/citation for that?

Comment: A colleague who is one of the deliverability managers of the email service provider which I'm working for. He looked it up in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft, as usual, has come up with their own proprietary alternative to the standard (at least they're consistent, I guess) called JMR - Junk Mail Reporting.